# when i run jupyter nitebook, i get the following error, can somebody help me?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.
>   py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>       File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.
>   py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>       File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\ju
>   pyter-notebook.EXE__main__.py", line 5, in 
>       File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-p
>   ackages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 28, in 
>       from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader   File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-p
>   ackages\jinja2__init__.py", line 33, in 
>       from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
>       File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-p
>   ackages\jinja2\environment.py", line 13, in 
>       from jinja2 import nodes
>       File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-p
>   ackages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in 
>       from jinja2.utils import Markup
>       File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-p
>   ackages\jinja2\utils.py", line 531, in 
>       from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
>       File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-p
>   ackages\markupsafe__init__.py", line 14, in 
>       from markupsafe._compat import text_type, string_types, int_types, \
>        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._compat'

---

I have tried

```
pip install markupsafe
```

Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe in

```
c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 7):

Just `pip uninstall markupsafe` and install it again with pip.Alternatively you can download a precompiled binary extension package from [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#markupsafe) and install the .whl file with pip.

Answer (score 5):

This solution works for me

`pip install markupsafe==2.0.1`

https://techoverflow.net/2022/04/07/how-to-fix-jupyter-lab-importerror-cannot-import-name-soft_unicode-from-markupsafe/